# How can I connect one of my View with UIView class?

Tags: ios, class, uiview

In my xib file I have some View. And I have PainView class (UIView). In the identity inspector I set `PaintView` for this View, and made `@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet PaintView *paintView;`

It was working Ok, until I desided to change draw method.
I copied code from this [file](https://github.com/levinunnink/Smooth-Line-View/blob/master/Smooth%20Line%20View/SmoothLineView.m) and pasted in PaintView.m (same with PaintView.h).

But it only works if I write

```
[self.view addSubview:[[PaintView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds]];
```

But it creates new layer over all other layers, buttons etc. And I need to connect this class with existing View.

I tried `paintView = [[PaintView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];` but it didnt work.

In console it always says invalid context:

```
<Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextGetBaseCTM: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextConcatCTM: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextSetBaseCTM: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextSetBaseCTM: invalid context 0x0
```

Can you help me, please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to implement another init method with the same initialization as in `initWithFrame:`
It's name is:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder 
{
  ...
}
```

`initWithCoder:` is the init method, that is called for view, loaded from NIB files.